# What is the "path"variable in rails integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, integration-testing

I was looking at the RailsGuides and I saw this example:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "login and browse site" do
    # login via https
    https!
    get "/login"
    assert_response :success

    post_via_redirect "/login", username: users(:david).username, password: users(:david).password
    assert_equal '/welcome', path
    assert_equal 'Welcome david!', flash[:notice]

    https!(false)
    get "/articles/all"
    assert_response :success
    assert assigns(:articles)
  end
end
```

I am confused about the variable "path" in the line `assert_equal '/welcome', path`. What is this exactly? Is this the url that would show up in your browser after we perform the `post_via_redirect` action right before it?

I looked into the helpers available in the integration tests, but the document didn't say anything about this "path" variable.

Additionally, I try it at my rails app and it works fine, but when I tried to call it at one of my controller tests, it gave me and `undefined local variables or method` error. So does it mean that the "path" variable is only available in the integration tests? What if I want to use it in the other types of tests?

Answer (score 0):

`path` is the url of your current page.

`path` is `request.url` without the domain name.

In this test you've been redirected from '/login' to '/welcome'.